# Why are my calls to these content engines failing when behind a proxy?

Tags: java, proxy, opencalais, zemanta

I am testing a couple of APIs and am undecided between Zemanta and OpenCalais.

I can use both perfectly at home, but at the company behind the proxy, they won't work, even when running the same examples.

I am running [this example](http://philippeadjiman.com/blog/2009/09/16/open-calais-from-java-with-eclipse-extract-entities-facts-and-events-in-4-minutes/) and [this](http://developer.zemanta.com/wiki), both Java.

How can I setup the proxy so it works?

Answer (score 4):

For Zemanta, this is what you need to do before you make the call,

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", proxyHost);
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", proxyPort);
```

Not familiar with Open Calais, you may have to do something different for it to work.

Comment: odd i tried in calais something like

URL url = new URL(u);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "proxy");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "port");
con.setRequestProperty("Proxy-Authorization", "Basic " + base64Encode(new String("user:pass")));

but thx, going to check tomorrow.